# Upload image using ajax request in Code igniter 4 throws null

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to upload image using ajax post request and save in controller in CI4.
But this shows me null object.

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({ 
                url: 'upload', 
                type: 'post', 
                data: {"image":img},   // img is the file which is being uploaded.
                contentType: false, 
                processData: false, 
                success: function(response){ 
                    if(response != 0){ 
                      html = '<img src="' + img + '" />';
                      $("#preview-crop-image").html(html);
                       alert('file uploaded'); 
                    } 
                    else{ 
                        alert('file not uploaded'); 
                    } 
                }, 
            }); 
});
```

Controller Code

```
public function image_upload()
{
    var_dump($this->request->getPost());
}
```

I'm trying to dump all the objects but not able to figure out.
What should be added over here?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 3.5.1 version is used

Comment: Instead of using field name, use FormData. This way you get everything in the form. https://www.tutsplanet.com/ajax-image-upload-using-php-and-jquery/

Comment: 1.Change  "type: 'POST' " to "method: 'POST' ". Type should be used in versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: 2. Check ajax post URL. Is it correct? If yes, check you CI4 router file it is pointed to correct controller and method

Answer (score 0):

Add forward slash to the url.

url: '/upload',